# python multithreading writing to file no result

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, python-3.5

I have the following code, which is a stripped-down version of a simulation program I'm writing:

```
import sched, time
import _thread as thread, threading

lock = threading.Lock()

f0=open("f0.out",'w',1)
f1=open("f1.out",'w',1)
f2=open("f2.out",'w',1)
# f3=open("f3.out",'w',1)
# f4=open("f4.out",'w',1)

# files = [f1,f2,f3,f4]
files = [f1,f2,]
def demoWrite(destFile):
    destFile.write("Hello\n")


def createSchedule(outFile):
    s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

    for i in range(1,100):
        s.enter(1,1,demoWrite,(outFile,))

    s.run()
    with lock:
        print('Thread Done',outFile)


createSchedule(f0)
f0.close()


for f in files:
    thread.start_new_thread ( createSchedule, (f,) )

for f in files:
    print(f)
    f.close()

print('Done')
```

The problem I'm having is that it creates the files, but does not write to them, nor does it print the `Thread Done` output.

for f0 however, which isn't threaded, it works without a hitch.

I get this same behaviour in the full program.

Comment: why are you using `_thread` directly instead of the `threading` module?

Comment: because I had a python 2.x tutorial, in which thread was a module of itself. Trying not to break the code, I adapted the import thread to import _thread as thread based on code I read somewhere else.

Comment: I belive you need to wait for the threads to finish before closing the files, normally you would use `Thread.join` to do this but you are not using the threading module so either handle the locks manually, use `time.sleep` and hope it is the right delay, or just use an updated tutorial...

Comment: I especially advice against the direct use of `_thread` if you are a beginner in need of a tutorial, the first step would probably catch the identifier value of [`thread.start_new_thread`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#thread.start_new_thread)

Answer (score 3):

Working code:

```
import sched, time
import threading

lock = threading.Lock()

f0=open("f0.out",'w',1)
f1=open("f1.out",'w',1)
f2=open("f2.out",'w',1)
# f3=open("f3.out",'w',1)
# f4=open("f4.out",'w',1)

# files = [f1,f2,f3,f4]
files = [f1,f2,]
def demoWrite(destFile):
    destFile.write("Hello\n")


def createSchedule(outFile):
    s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

    for i in range(1,100):
        s.enter(1,1,demoWrite,(outFile,))

    s.run()
    with lock:
        print('Thread Done',outFile)
        outFile.close()


createSchedule(f0)
f0.close()


for f in files:
    t = threading.Thread(target=createSchedule, args=(f,))
    t.start()
    # thread.start_new_thread (  )


print('Done')
```

What I did:

- import threading instead of _thread
- change thread creation to `t = threading.Thread(target=createSchedule, args=(f,)); t.start()`

thank you Tadhg McDonald-Jensen for your comment, which pointed me in the right direction

Comment: closing the file in the thread is a really good idea, glad you got it working :)